# GIT uses and purpose

Tags: git

I was task to explain and make a demo on our class about GIT. I have been following the [GIT Book](http://git-scm.com/book) to have git working  and I was reading others tutorial. As I read more and more, I get very confuse. Everything stated in the tutorials seems very technical, its hard for a student to understand which doesn't have any idea about.

I was given a server access with our professor. I followed the steps stated [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) to setup my server. I did the following:

```
$ ssh myusername@myprofessorserver.com 
$ sudo adduser git
$ su git
$ cd
$ mkdir .ssh
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@mailserver.com"
$ cat /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa.myusername.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ cd /home/git
$ mkdir myfirstproject.git
$ cd myfirstproject.git
$ git --bare init
$ ls
$ ./   .bash_history  .bash_profile  devsite.git/  perl5/       public_html/
```

../  .bash_logout   .bashrc        .emacs        public_ftp/  .ssh/

```
$ cd devsite.git
$ ls
$./  ../  branches/  config  description  HEAD  hooks/  info/  objects/  refs/
```

I dont know what else are lacking in my configuration to have git worked. The server is running into Fedora.

I am using a windows PC, to configure my local site I downloaded the files msysgit.github.com/, I selected "pure users of GIT, in google download link." I just run the installation and followed all steps. I used NETBeans as my IDE. I followed the tutorial in netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html. But I have only followed step 1, the rest of the steps I did not able to make it work. I was stuck on number 2 steps.

Any idea on what else do i need to do to have git work on my local and on my remote server? What did i missed with my steps above?  If its my first project, I don't have any file yet, what do I need to do with my server setup?

I only need 2 test files to add in the server and show to my classmates the presentation Files are only index.html and welcomemessage.html And my repository and branch name is empty yet

Any advice from anyone on this matter?

Comment: There's something very screwy going on in that command sequence and it has nothing to do with git.  In particular, `cd /home/git; mkdir myfirstproject.git; cd myfirstproject.git; git --bare init; ls' cannot possibly produce the output you show.

Comment: What version of Git are you on? Are you on your Windows PC or the server? There can be a few tweaks needed to ensure the Git for Windows (aka msysgit, though that is the compilable source) will get paths correct etc. I may be better to simply use GitHub as your server as they do a lot of the server setup work, and you only need to do the 'user' work.

Comment: Are you trying to explain the 'technical Git', or explain the whys and wherefores? Many folk just don't get Git's working concepts until they have tripped up a few times. Git takes on board many concepts all in one big leap: Manage the project, not the files. Everyone gets a full copy. Validation as the norm (equality of sha1s). Personal lines of development (branches). Staging (prep/reworking of your 'out-box') before committing (filing). It solves a lot of problems most folk don't realise they (their projects) have.

Answer (score 0):

Give this tutorial a shot:

http://www.rosipov.com/blog/create-gitolite-repository/

This is easiest and non-deprecated way to maintain a git repository.

Comment: Without even mentioning this approach relies on gitolite -- a third-party tool?!

Answer (score 0):

That is (part) of what in required to set up a bare (non work) repository. But most of the time I use git just for it version control, purely locally. I.e., to keep track of some program I'm writing, or a LaTeX document source. No sharing, just version control:

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
git init
# Hack away, commit, branch, ...
```

Some of those I have several times (on my laptop and on my netbook):

```
git clone git://laptop.example.com/home/vonbrand/myrepo
# Hack away
git push
```

For others I've set up a bare repo on a fixed machine (for backup, mainly). A few I share with the world trhough gitosis.